# How to build Angular 4.3.6 for production?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, uglifyjs, tree-shaking

I have some questions about an Angular 4 app in production created with angular-cli which uses Webpack.

Is `ng build --prod --aot` the best command for create the final bundle to deploy into a production environment?

If yes, is Tree shaking and AOT and Uglfy configured by default through angular-cli or am I supposed to configure these manually?

Is there any other best practice or advice in bundling an Angular 4 app developed with angular-cli?

I use @angular/cli version 1.3.1.

Comment: Nope use ng build --prod --aot for the best build in production.

Comment: --prod will uglify build --aot will do aot :-)

Comment: via angular-cli nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  According to the [angular-cli documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds) on this these are the settings used for the --prod flag:

```
--aot true
--environment prod
--output-hashing all
--sourcemaps false
--extract-css true
--named-chunks   false
```

It also does this:

- Adds service worker if configured in .angular-cli.json.
- Replaces process.env.NODE_ENV in modules with the production value.
- Runs UglifyJS on the code.

So using `ng build --prod` is all you need to do and angular-cli will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

> Is ng build --prod --aot the best command for create the final bundle to deploy in prodcution stage...?

I can be short about this, Yes

> If yes, is Tree shaking and AOT and Uglfy configured by default throught Angular-cli or i am supposed to configure it manually ?

You don't need to configure it manually. It's already there.

> Is there's any other best method or advice to bundle an Angular 4 app developed via Angular-cli ...?

You can use the experimental option `build-optimizer=true` to further decrease you application size. Note, it is experimental.